# how can we call the onBackPressed() function from Custom Adapter

Tags: android, onclick

### how can we back to the first activity from a adapter button click

```
holder.close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        onBackPressed(); 
                    }
                }) ;
            return convertView;
        }
```

Comment: Are you passing the `Activity` context in your constructor?

Comment: Why don't you use Intent to go back to previous activity OR just finish the current activity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if your previous activity is on stack just call -

```
((Activity) mContext).finish();
```

else
call previous activity using intent & finish current activity.

```
holder.close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent mIntent=new Intent(mContext,MyActivity.class);
                    mContext.startActivity(mIntent);
                    ((Activity) mContext).finish();
                }
            }) ;
        return convertView;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can write code in Activity's  onBackPressed() method for going to previous activity,and then give call to activity's onBackPressed() method from adapter.

```
((Your Activity)context).onBackPressed();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Context.finish();
```

use activity context.finish();

Comment: have you did it ?...do it and than reply its not working

Comment: If its not working then show your adapter class first.

Comment: instead of putting Context u have to use your activity context

Answer (score 1):

Just finish the current activity using context.
use this :

```
 holder.close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                      ((Activity)context).finish();
                    }
                }) ;
            return convertView;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not finishing first activity while starting new activity, then you can just finish the current activity.

```
holder.close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //finish this activity
    }
 });
```

Comment: hello thank you fro replying but i am calling from a adapter how can i tell me

Answer (score 0):

For That u need to pass the Activity in your custom adapter cunstructor and and use the onBackPress() Function..

e.g.

....

```
 Activity mctx;
 MyAdapter(Activity a) {

 mctx = a;
 }
```

...

```
 holder.close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    mctx.onBackPressed(); 
                }
            }) ;
        return convertView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

pass activity reference to adapter via constructor like:

`CustomAdapter customAdapter=CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
arrayList,HomeActivity.this);`

and in Your Custom Adapter

```
 public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder> {

Context context;
ArrayList<HomeModel> arrHomeModel;
AppCompatActivity activity;
public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HomeModel> arrHomeModel, AppCompatActivity activity)
{
    this.context=context;
    this.arrHomeModel=arrHomeModel;
    this.activity=activity;
}
```

Now you can call activity.onBackPressed(); wherever you want.